# How do I pop up an alert in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, alert

How do I pop up an alert in JavaScript?

I tried `alert"HELLO"` but that didn't work.

Can someone tell me the correct syntax?

Comment: Have a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert

Answer (score 12):

You need to add parentheses:

```
alert("HELLO");
```

Answer (score 12):

Unlike VBScript, JavaScript requires parentheses around function calls.

Therefore, you need to write `alert("Hello!");`

It's also preferable (but not required) to end every statement with a semicolon `;`.

Finally, if you aren't already, you need to put it in a script block, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello!");
</script>
```

You can put JavaScript inside a script tag in an HTML page, or you can make a standalone `.js` file and double-click on it (in Windows) to run it using WSH.

Comment: I realize this is old, but I encourage you to cite your claim that _semicolons are preferable_, because there are widely accepted (unofficial) standards that enforce otherwise, [like this one](https://standardjs.com/).

Answer (score 5):

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  alert("hello");
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

if you're having problems with alerts, it probably means your javascript is disabled in your browser, but if it isn't these methods should solve your issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    window.alert("Hello World!");

    alert("Hello World!");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add parantheses

```
alert("Hello");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello");</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways.

1. Use your web browser, type this code in address bar.

   `javascript:alert("Hello World!")`
2. Open web developer in your web browser, go to console and type:

   `alert("Hello World!")`
3. Type the code in .html or .js code as shown in other answers above.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myFunction(){
    alert("hello");
  }
</script>
 </head>
<body>
<input type="submit" onClick="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JavaScript function which has an alert box. This function is called by clicking on the submit button.